# How to check if all Textbox is empty in on click and input thier errorProvider msg?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, errorprovider

I want to check if any textbox is empty on btn click and then display their corresponding SetError msg on their side

```
bool isIncomplete = false;
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
        {
            isIncomplete = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} // I think this.controls does not work properly..

if (isIncomplete)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(firstname_txtbox, "First Name is required.");
    errorProvider2.SetError(lastname_txtbox, "Last Name is required.");

    MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the textbox correctly!");
    return;

} else if(firstname_txtbox.Text.Length < 2)
{ 
  errorProvider1.SetError(firstname_txtbox, "First Name need to be at least 2 characters"); //this error message does appear through...
}else if() { etc..
```

The errorProvider message arent being dispalyed on click.
My textboxes are inside a Panel...

Comment: you need to iterate through the controls of the panel and not of the form. One shortcut: `this.panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` will return only the textboxes

Comment: thanks, i think its working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33080822/3110834

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129052/3110834

Answer (score 0):

use [String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IsNullOrEmpty_System_String_)
 to check if a control is empty.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the textbox correctly!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not empty");
        }
    }
```