# Validating textbox content if checkbox has been checked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

I'm trying to do a validation wherein if a checkbox has been ticked, the corresponding textbox would no longer be in `ReadOnly` mode and should not be empty. For example, if I checked `CheckBox1`, if `TextBox1` did not have any input, a `MessageBox` would pop up to say that *"Please fill up the entire form!"*. Else, it would display *"Done!"*.

This is what I have so far:

```
if ((CheckBox1.Checked && TextBox1.Text == "") 
    || (CheckBox2.Checked && TextBox2.Text == ""))
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the entire form!");

else if (CheckBox1.Checked && TextBox1.Text != "")
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");

else if (CheckBox2.Checked && TextBox2.Text != "")
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

I've made a couple of checkboxes/textboxes that would require this validation and I find that it gets kind of lengthy so I was wondering if there's a simpler/better approach.

*(not sure if relevant) Note: I got the toggling the ReadOnly mode when the CheckChanged event is triggered part down*

Comment: Do you need those `else if`?

Comment: Are you aware that `CheckBox1.Checked == true` is exaxtly the same as `CheckBox1.Checked`?

Comment: @oerkelens silly me thanks for that! I always thought i had to do that

Comment: @RezaAghaei well at least I think I do. Do you think I don't and can suggest a better way to go around it?

Comment: You can return from method if there is some validation error and don't write those `else if` part. Just put the code which should be executed after validations.

Comment: You would be in luck had you tried this in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be some enhancements for your code, for example:

- You can use this criteria `!textBox.ReadOnly && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)` rather than what you have.
- You can avoid using those `else if` parts and just `return` from the method if there is a validation error and just put the code after the validation block.

**A better solution - Using `Validating` Event**

But I'd rather to change the whole style of validation and use `Validating` event of those `TextBox` controls. To do so, you need to follow these instructions:

1) Set `AutoValidate` property of form to `EnableAllowFocusChange` in design mode or using code in Load event of form.

2) Handle `Validating` event of all `TextBox` controls using single a method and set `e.Cancel = true;` when there is validation error:

```
private void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (!textBox.ReadOnly && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

3) In the save button of your form, using `ValidateChildren` method of the form, check if there is any validation error, show a message, otherwise do what the button is supposed to do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.ValidateChildren())
        MessageBox.Show("Please correct validation errors.")
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Done!")
}
```

**Note**

To read more about validation options in Windows Forms, take a look at this post:

- [Validating user input / Give .NET controls status OK or NOK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35993185/3110834)

Also if you want to enhance the user experience by showing a validation error/icon near the control using an `ErrorProvider`, take a look at this post:

- [Validation using Validating event and ErrorProvider - Show Error Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33080822/3110834)

Comment: Oh so this is what you meant. Thank you so much for that elaborate explanation. Worked like a charm! :)

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at linked posts as well. Maybe it seems too much for a simple application, but knowing facilities is a key point which will help you when creating more complicated and more professional applications.

Comment: I got around to just now. The detailed explanations are really helpful. Thank you!